# C++ want to return to where left off

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;



int main()
{
    int password;

    system("cls");
    cout <<"Login"<< endl;
    cout <<"Enter password to continue"<< endl;
    cin >> password;
    cin.ignore().get();

          if( password == 1111)
          {

              system("cls");
              cout <<"Access Granted"<< endl;
              system("PAUSE");
              system("cls");
              return main();
          }
          //Want to make if( password == 1111) return to main(), but start    where it left off
          //I want it to start at cout <<"Files:'<< endl; 
                  cout <<"Files:"<< endl;
                  cout <<"\n E \n N \n G \n S \n"<< endl;
                  cout <<"Choose a file"<< endl;
                  string file;
                  cin >> file;
                  cin.ignore().get();

                                 if(file == "E" || file == "e")
                                 {
                                         system("cls");
                                         cout <<"E:"<< endl;
                                         cout <<"Age:"<< endl;
                                         cout <<"Grade:"<< endl;
                                         cout <<"Eye color:"<< endl;
                                         cout <<"Hair color:"<< endl; 
                                         system("Pause");     
                                 }

                                 else if(file == "N" || file == "n")
                                 {
                                      system("cls");
                                      cout <<"N:"<< endl;
                                      cout <<"Age:"<< endl;
                                      cout <<"Grade:"<< endl;
                                      cout <<"Eye color:"<< endl;
                                      cout <<"Hair color:"<< endl;
                                      system("Pause");

                                 }        

                                 else if(file == "G" || file == "g")
                                 {
                                      system("cls");
                                      cout <<"G:"<< endl;
                                      cout <<"Age:"<< endl;
                                      cout <<"Eye color:"<< endl;
                                      cout <<"Hair color:"<< endl;
                                      system("Pause");         
                                 }        

                                 else if(file == "S" || file == "s")
                                 {
                                      system("cls");
                                      cout <<"S:"<< endl;
                                      cout <<"Age:"<< endl;
                                      cout <<"Eye color:"<< endl;
                                      cout <<"Hair color:"<< endl;
                                      system("Pause");         
                                 }        
          else
          {
              system("cls");
              cout<<"Access Denied!"<< endl;
              system("PAUSE");
              return 0;    
          }

    return 0;
}
```

Having trouble figuring out how to continue where the main function left of. I have been teaching myself how to code so I don't know if that's even possible. Read the comment I left In the code to better understand what I am speaking of. Thx

Comment: *Want to make if( password == 1111) return to main(), but start    where it left off
   I want it to start at cout <<"Files:'<< endl;* The code, as it is now, will do exactly that if you remove the call `return main()`. Besides, don't call `main` from `main` or any of the functions that you define. The standard does not allow that.

Comment: if(password == 1111) // do your stuff, else continue down with the path.You dont need to do anything extra.remove the recursive call to main().That is inappropriate

Comment: Btw, what's up with your indentation? The indentation in this program doesn't match its actual structure.

Comment: The else block at the end of the code looks like it should  after the } of the first if.

Comment: Indentation in c++ has no special significance, it's for human readability only.

Answer (score 0):

If you remove this line:

```
return main();
```

then the computer will continue executing the instructions in the order they are written - in particular, the next one will be `cout <<"Files:"<< endl;`.

Answer (score 0):

To control the flow of your program, you have multiple options.

If you're doing things multiple times, you have `for` and `while` loops. If you want to stop a loop and get out, use `break`. If you want to skip to the next iteration, use `continue`.

If you want to simply jump to a different place in the program, you can use `goto` but it's a code smell. It's generally better to avoid it as it tends to compromise readability.

If you want to do a task that can he interrupted, you can use a `void function`. If you want the function to stop what it's doing and continue `main`, use `return`.

---

However, in your particular example, it seems like you don't quite understand how an `if` statement works.
If the `if`s condition is true, it executes whatever is in the curly braces (`{ ... }`). It continues execution right after the closing brace automatically. **You don't need to return to main explicitly.**

What you actually did there (by mistake) is write a *recursive function* (one that calls itself until a condition is met).

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have significantly misunderstood program flow in a C++ program. `return main()` will make a fresh call into main, so the user will see the "login" prompt again. When that call to main has ended, because you used the keyword `return`, it will exit the previous call to main. Neither of these is what you want. It's also explicitly forbidden by the C++ standard to call main from another function.

I also note that after the long block of indented functionality, you have an else statement that looks like it is the else to `if (password == 1111)`.

Indentation means nothing to the C++ compiler, it's purely for human readability.

I think what you are trying to achieve is something more like this:

```
if (password == 1111)
{
    std::cout << "Access granted\n";
}
else
{
    std::cout << "Access denied\n";
    return 0;
}

std::cout << "Files:\n";
```

Here, if the user types 1111, then the first compound block of code is executed, and execution resumes after the end of the if/else block, i.e. the next instruction is to print Files.

If the user types something else, the `else` block is executed. It finishes with `return 0` which exits the function and returns the value of 0 to the caller.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Login:\n";
    std::string password;
    std::getline(std::cin, password);

    if (password == "1111")
        std::cout << "That's correct.\n";
    else {
        std::cout << "Access denied.\n";
        return 0;
    }

    std::cout << "Files:\n";

    // your code here
}
```

Demo: http://ideone.com/DSYAG4

Comment: Thank you so much. Been stuck for a couple of days.

Comment: @NathanTurner If it was helpful, please accept (click the checkmark) and/or upvote the answer.